Can't add cache for my dependencies in GitHub Actions using Python
I have a project that uses ruff and pytest. I want to cache those dependencies, but in the docs there is an example that uses some kind of node.js env, and chatGPT suggested me something like that:
name: Code analysis

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: main

jobs:
  analyze:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - name: Check out repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Cache pip
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ matrix.python-version }}-ruff-pytest
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ matrix.python-version }}-
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install ruff
        pip install pytest
    - name: Run Ruff
      run: |
        ruff check script.py tests.py
    - name: Run pytest
      run: |
        pytest tests.py

Error logs for Cache pip:
Run actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: ~/.cache/pip
    key: Linux-pip-3.8-ruff-pytest
    restore-keys: Linux-pip-3.8-
  
    enableCrossOsArchive: false
    fail-on-cache-miss: false
    lookup-only: false
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib
Cache not found for input keys: Linux-pip-3.8-ruff-pytest, Linux-pip-3.8-

Which of course doesn't work. Do I need to add requirements.txt or some other dependency management to my project or can I somehow make GitHub Actions cache the result of the pip commands?

Have you checked the log to see when the cache is written? In my opinion, only during the post processes.

Added the logs for Cache pip process @Bademeister

You did not show your full workflow, nor the error/observations from the run. I will attempt a suggestion based on what is on the question.
You do not need requirements.txt to enable caching. If you are not using a matrix strategy in your job, please try removing ${{ matrix.python-version }}.
Make sure that your yaml is valid and has correct indentation.
You may also want to execute this command to confirm cache dir
pip cache dir

Update after seeing the complete workflow.
The workflow looks fine. It is expected to see the message "Cache not found for input keys: Linux-pip-3.8-ruff-pytest, Linux-pip-3.8-" on the first run.
If the workflow succeeds you should see logs for Post Run actions/cache@v3 step like these:
Post job cleanup.
/usr/bin/tar --posix -cf cache.tzst --exclude cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/actions-exam/actions-exam --files-from manifest.txt --use-compress-program zstdmt
Cache Size: ~12 MB (13021200 B)
Cache saved successfully
Cache saved with key: Linux-pip-3.8-ruff-pytest

On the subsequent runs of the workflow you should wee this in the logs of step Run actions/cache@v3
Cache Size: ~12 MB (13021200 B)
/usr/bin/tar -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/81b1d738-8d6d-4c5b-a0fc-ee17d4f5857f/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/actions-exam/actions-exam --use-compress-program unzstd
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-pip-3.8-ruff-pytest

However, if the workflow fails due to a non zero exit code in one of the steps, cache will not be created because Post Run actions/cache@v3 step will not run.
Tried with this workflow:
name: Cache

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  analyze:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - run: pip cache dir
      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ matrix.python-version }}-ruff-pytest
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ matrix.python-version }}-
      - run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install ruff
          pip install pytest
      - run: ruff help


I am using matrix strategy. Updating the main post with the whole YAML and the error messages

How to make subsequent runs without changing the code?

I used workflow_dispatch for manual triggering.  See workflow in my answer.

Adding workflow_dispatch to the on: triggers will provides a "Run workflow" button when you select this workflow from a list of workflows on the left hand-side panel in GitHub UI
